# How to install package wkhtmltopdf in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf, dpkg

I've used dpkg to install deb packages, but now you can only get the files without an install file. ie (bin, include, lib, share folders) but no .sh or install file.

How can I install this?

Thanks
Download Source:
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: try take a look from this link
https://askubuntu.com/questions/556667/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-0-12-1-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: his Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com  (Unix & Linux).  Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the tar file, put it at somewhere ,then create a soft link to the bin file,like this:

```
sudo ln -s xxxx/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

That all